# Using ActiveRecord in Ruby On Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have 3 models, Customer, Package and location.

The customer logs in, and can view  a timeline of locations for his packages.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base

def find_all_by_customer(customer)
  self.joins(:packages => :customer).where("customers.id = ?", customer).select("DISTINCT(locations.id), locations.name, locations.created_at")
end
```

returns the customer all the locations for all his packages, so they can be displayed on the timeline.

The part I am struggling with, is then displaying the package number/s next to each of these locations. The problem is the package numbers are dependant on both the current_user, and the location.

```
<% @locations.each do |location| %>
  <%= location.name %>
  <%= # Want to display all package numbers in this location for the logged in user. %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What is the package number and how does it depend on the current_user and location?

Comment: It's just a unique reference for that package. It depends on a user, as a user is receiving that package, and it depends on a location as the package has to be at a location at any time.

Comment: How is the package number defined then? Is it generated everytime the package changes it's location? I don't see it queried in your select statement.I'm sorry, I don't understand how it's supposed to work :)

Comment: Every package will have the same number for its lifetime, you could just use its id field.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like `location.package.reference_number`, if your associations are setup correctly.

Comment: That will give me all reference numbers for all the packages at a particular location, but i also want them to also be restricted by the current user.